# want multiple, independent requests resolved concurrently before a final, dependent action (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

Promises are one of those things that I can understand while I'm looking at them, but then the comprehension vanishes when I look away.

I need to grab two pieces of data asynchronously, then combine the result and store it in a cookie. I think I could implement a vanilla promise chain without much difficulty. That is,

```
loadData1().then(loadData2).then(setCookie);
```

However, I don't *need* to wait for one request to finish before making the other. How can I do something like

```
(loadData1(); loadData2();).then(setCookie);
```

Comment: Oh, I just found `$q.all()`. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using `$q.all`:

```
$q.all([
    (function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        API.get({}, function (data) {
            d.resolve(data);
        });
        return d.promise;
    })(),
    (function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        API.getMore({}, function (data) {
            d.resolve(data);
        });
        return d.promise;
    })()
]).then(function(responses) {
    //responses contains an array of all your data responses, in the order they were chained to $q
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up with.